# What does "writing intentions" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning, descriptive-grammar

In the following line, I'm not sure what "writing intentions" means at the end.

> "Even if you've written 20 scripts before, perhaps you need help on
>   dialogue, a clearer inciting incident, stronger actions to avoid
>   writing intentions."

"To avoid"? Wow it completely befuddled me there. "Avoid writing intentions"? Isn't "writing" the whole point? How would "avoiding" (it) achieve anything? It defeats the purpose don't you think?

First I thought it may be "Writing(, but) 'intentions'". Alternatively, "Writing-intentions" perhaps?

Yet again it could mean something altogether different, that I've never come across.

Any thoughts on this, be appreciated :)

p.s. Since I've been prompted to reword the above, (and am at a loss,) I'd just re-emphasise "writing intentions".  Whatever does it mean here? Or anywhere for that matter?

Comment: In the absence of a full context (the text before/after the cited sentence) I think this question can only be answered with guesses, so it's "Unclear".

Comment: The reason this was closed is because *it lacks context*. We know you don't understand *"writing intentions"*, so the post-closure edit adds nothing. Why can't you simply provide more context (for example, a link to the full text within which the cited fragment occurs?). But it's unlikely that would contradict Gorpik's guess at the meaning anyway.

Comment: really? how come I had gotten some "fitting" answers anyway? magic?

Comment: @ Effector: Presumably it won't have escaped your notice that although currently 6 users have upvoted Gorpik's "guess" (as "probably correct"), no-one has upvoted your *question*. Obviously your cited text can't be very well expressed if you couldn't understand it (in a full context which you *still* haven't provided). Whatever - you're happy with your answer, and I can't see the question as it stands has any relevance to future visitors, so I think it may as well be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, I think it means *to avoid having to write intentions*. This is: if you have a clearer inciting incident and stronger actions, you will not need to write what are the intentions of the characters, since they will already be clear for the audience.

Comment: Agreed. The advice seems to be in accord with the traditional scriptwriter's guideline -- essentially, "Don't tell it; show it".

Comment: This solution cannot possibly be more correct. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Agreed I suppose it could have been more clearly written as,  "...to avoid ***explicitly*** writing intentions."